# Extract first number

Tags: javascript

how can i extract the first number from this array?
The number is taken from the variable and then divided, from 0222 to [ 0, 2, 2, 2 ]
I need to check the first number, but I can't.

thank you

```js
var cellF9 = sh.getRange(9, 6, 1, 1).getValue();

  String(cellF9).split("").map(Number);
  function splitNum(num) {
    return String(num).split("").map(Number);
  }

  console.log(splitNum(cellF9));

  switch (cellF9[0]) {
    case 0:
      sh.getRange("F18").setValue("test");
      break;
    default:
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(".......", ".............", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);

  }
```

Comment: read about Array.splice. in some implementations you might also find Array.shift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `switch (cellF9[0]) {` you are indexing against the original string `"0222"`. You can either do

```js
switch (splitNum(cellF9[0])) {
```

or

```js
const splittedNumber = splitNum(cellF9[0])
switch (splittedNumber) {
```

A solution without splitting it into an array:

```js
const cell = '0222'
console.log(cell.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]
const firstElement = array[0]
```

Have you tried just accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

solved thanks :)

```js
var arrayf9=splitNum(cellF9); 

  switch (arrayf9[0]) {
..........
..........
```